# How to indent multi-line clearcase comment using cleartool format (-fmt)

Tags: command-line, clearcase, cleartool

Is it possible to re-create standard "desc" command indenting of comments using cleartool format string?

Example:

`cleartool desc <version>` outputs something like

```
version "<extended version path>"
created <date> by <user>
  "comment line 1
   comment line 2
   ...
   comment line n"
...
```

Is there -fmt option to create similar output with custom format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, regarding the indent part.
[`fmt_ccase` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) does propose the extended version path, date, user and comment, but you can only put spaces or tabs (ie 'escape sequences') in front of each fields, not put tabs *in the middle* of one of those fields (like tabs in front of each lines of a comment)

```
cleartool descr -fmt "version \"%Xn\"\ncreated %d by %u\n\t\"%c\"" afile
```

Note than one of the examples seems to indicates that spaces put in front of a field are repeated for all the lines of that field:

> Mimic the output from `lshistory –long`.
>   Note that in `cleartool` single-command mode, backslashes (`\`) are used to escape double quotes in the format string.

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "%d      %Fu (%u@%h)\n  %e \"%n\"\n  \"%Nc\"\n"  util.c 
2007-05-11T09:24:38     Anne Duvo (anne@neptune)
  create version "util.c@@\main\3"
  "fix bug r2-307"
2007-05-10T09:09:29     Ravi Singha (ravi@mercury)
  create version "util.c@@\main\2"
  "ready for code review"
.
.
.
```

Comment: Pity, I was hoping you will know the answer :) I went through format manual but did not find any way to do that. It seems strange, it would be logical if format string will allow same kind of control as predefined formats. One thing which is still not clear to me is %i conversion, but I could not make it work.